# Show that $v$ mod $2$ = $w$ mod $2$ if and only if $\alpha$ mod $2$ = $\beta$ mod $2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

**Basic setting**:

1) Let $N$ be an even  integer, and $a$ and $b$ are two odd integers in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ such that $\gcd{(N, a)}=\gcd{(N, b)}=1$. Thus there exist $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ and we have $aa^{-1}=\alpha N+1$ and $bb^{-1}=\beta N+1$ for some integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

2) With the above assumption, let $d=\gcd{(N, a-b)}=\gcd{(N, a^{-1}-b^{-1})}$, $u=N/d$, $v=(a-b)/d$ and $w=(a^{-1}-b^{-1})/d$. We are only interested in the case that $u$ is odd, so assume that $u$ is odd.

**Question**:

I want to prove that the following statement is true:

$v$ mod $2$ = $w$ mod $2$ if and only if $\alpha$ mod $2$ = $\beta$ mod $2$.

**Example**:

$N=18$, $a=17$ and $b=11$. Then $a^{-1}=17$, $b^{-1}=5$, $d=6$, $u=3$, $v=1$ and $w=2$.
In this case, we can see that

$v$ mod $2$ $\neq$ $w$ mod $2$ and $\frac{17\times 17-1}{18}$ mod $2$ $\neq$ $\frac{11\times 5-1}{18}$ mod $2$.